# Can I use Hong Kong dollars in Guangzhou?

Tags: money, china, guangzhou

I've read that you [usually can't](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4573/can-i-spend-renminbi-in-hong-kong) use Renminbi in Hong Kong.

Is it possible to use Hong Kong dollars in Guangzhou (Canton)?

Comment: No in 99.999999999999% of the cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally no. HK$ in Hong Kong. RMB in China. However, there are plenty of ATMs where your normal bank card should be able to get you cash at a reasonable rate. Some banks have "no-fee" agreements with partner banks in China. For me that's Westpac in AUS and China Construction Bank in mainland China.